# Spring OAuth server + client + REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

```
 Mobile MyProject app      Spring MyProject backend
      |                              |
      |------------ FB token ------->|
      |                              |
      |<------ MyProject token ------|
```

State of my project:

- websecurity for standard Spring Security user authentication
- `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` with `@EnableAuthorizationServer` to provide OAuth server feature and endpoints
- `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` with `@EnableOAuth2Client` to provide user authentication using Facebook OAuth

I have some HTML that provides login/password and Facebook standard authentication. After that, the user is able to request a MyProject authorization code so that any app using a proper OAuth client can get a token using this code. And this works well for my web HTML apps.

But I would like my native app to use its own UI to get a MyProject token in the end. For login + password it's easy, I can use the `password` grant type of my authorization server. But for Facebook, I have no easy mean to do it. The native app produces the FB token, and then has to exchange it for a MyProject token.

**My question**: how could I build a REST endpoint that takes a FB token and returns a "MyProject" token? (not asking how to declare an endpoint but how this endpoint would work of course)

I know I can do this with `/oauth/token` endpoint doing some customization in my user details service to detect a FB token and handle it specifically. But what I really want is avoid doing the FB calls by hand when I already have the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, `OAuth2RestTemplate`, user details and authority extractors, and `UserInfoTokenServices` for Facebook.

What is the cleanest hook to do this?

Comment: So you want to wrap Facebook authorization with your own one? user logins -> your auth -> facebook auth -> return facebook token -> return your token?

Comment: No, more: user logs in to my app in FB and gets a FB token -> sends to my backend -> my backend returns my project's token.

Comment: so to get your token, user request 2 times to your endpoint? 1st request -> returns FB token, than 2nd request with FB token -> returns your token. If so, is there any reason for this flow?

Comment: No, sorry if I'm not clear: there's a client iOS app FB flow that produces the FB token outside of my backend and HTML ecosystem, and I want that from this token, my iOS client is able to get a "My project" token using a REST endpoint.

Comment: Just edited my question again so that it's hopefully much clearer.